# Chrome renders fonts poorly at developer.android.com

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

I'm currently running Chrome 20.0.1132.57 on two PCs.

PC #1: Windows 7 64-bit
PC #2: Windows Server 2008 64-bit SP2

On the 2008 machine Chrome is rendering fonts inconsistently, but as far as I know, only on *developer.android.com/reference*. I have not seen this problem anywhere else.

Here are some images of the problem:

Poor rendering on 2008:

[image]

Good rendering on 2008, same browser window, different site:

[image]

Good rendering on Windows 7, same browser version:

[image]

The browsers on each OS are practically identical in terms of settings. I've played with my Windows ClearType settings, which didn't help. Similar threads suggest disabling GPU acceleration in about:flags, but I can't find anything similar that's not already disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Gareth for fixing my images. I assumed I couldn't post them since I only have 1 rep. Superuser however resized them. The problem isn't quite as noticable in the shrunken images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poor rendering you see in Windows 2008 is because both ClearType and standard font smoothing are turned off. The Roboto regular font (used in Android website) looks particularly jagged because it’s not [hinted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) to support Windows’ font rendering, as Android OS doesn’t need it.

You might want to [enable ClearType in Windows 2008](http://vistasupport.mvps.org/turn_on_off_cleartype.htm), or [install an alternative font renderer](https://superuser.com/q/108312/106312).

Comment: The taskbar and tooltip in the first two screenshots do show ClearType, though.

Comment: @horsedrowner That’s because it’s not possible to turn off ClearType for certain parts of Windows Vista+. For example, ClearType is always enabled in IE, Windows Explorer and Aero.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Forgot about that.